# React Redux cleaning the store - when?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-lifecycle

I have an app written in react hooks, I manage my data with redux,
we use `redux-persist` in order to prevent clean store on each page refresh.
but, I want to clean up the store at the end of application life (close the tab or close all the browser),
I tried `useEffect clean-up function` in App.js, but it's didn't work.
where is the correct place of the end of application life?

Answer (score 1):

If you're talking about truly closing down the application, then no "store cleanup" is needed. A Redux store is just a normal JS variable, and like all other JS variables, it will be cleaned up when the page is closed and the entire JS runtime environment is destroyed.

Comment: The redux store not cleaned on close. (you can check it with Redux chrome extantion)

Comment: You are telling that to the author of the last version of react-redux there ;)
If you do not explicitly use something like `redux-persist` to keep the state longer than that (which you do not state in the question), redux state will be lost on application close.

Comment: you are correct, we use redux-persist, I edited the question accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Since redux-persist works by saving your state in local storage, this should most probably work.

```
window.onunload = () => {
     // Clear the local storage
    window.localStorage.clear();
}
```

> Redux persist is a library allowing to save the redux store in the
> local storage of your browser.

[localStorage.clear()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_storage_clear.asp)

Comment: This function called also when refreshing the page

Comment: normally when u uses an webapp there is no reason to refresh page. Your page unloads and reloads and reinitiate all values.